# How can I append datagridview data to an existing Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I can send datagridview data to a new Excel file. I want to append datagridview data to an existing Excel file's sheet. I take an error this code snippet.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\file.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in App.exe
>
> Additional information: Ne yazık ki C:\file.xls öğesini bulamadık.
>   Taşınmış, yeniden adlandırılmış veya silinmiş olabilir mi?

I have file.xls on Disc C. What is wrong?

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of your code, but copy/paste it.

Comment: @bluefeet I edited the question. if it appropriate, could you please reopen it?

Comment: @team16sah reopened.